# How do I change the view a URL resolves to after a certain date?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.5, url-pattern, django-formwizard

I'm writing a contest app. The contest closes at midnight on a particular date. I want to have the app automatically switch from: using a `CookieWizardView`, from `formtools`; to a normal `TemplateView`, from the generic view library.

Currently the relevant part of my urlpatterns looks like this:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'appname.views.contest'), # the CookieWizardView
)
```

and I'd like it, after a certain date, to act as though it looks like this:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'appname.views.contestclosed'), # a TemplateView
)
```

I am totally, *totally* fine with having a hard-coded magic number, I just don't want to be up at midnight that day!

~~

I solved this but can't answer my own question because I'm too new.

I made a function in my `views.py`:

```
def contest_switcher(request):
    if datetime.datetime.now() < datetime.datetime(YEAR_OVER, MONTH_OVER, DAY_OVER):
        return contest(request)
    else:
        return contestclosed(request)
```

This does the trick, now my urlpattern is:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'appname.views.contest_switcher'),
)
```

I did have to add a function to my contest closed view, though, because it wasn't expecting a POST, which could happen if someone is trying to fill out the contest form at midnight:

```
class ContestClosedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "appname/closed.html"

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(*args, **kwargs)

contestclosed = ContestClosedView.as_view()
```

Comment: Why don't you just compare the date in the view itself and change which template is rendered (and with what context)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to try to hack your `urls.py` to pull this off. Set one URL pattern that points to a view that looks like this:

```
def contest_page(request, contest_id):
    try:
        contest = Contest.objects.get(pk=contest_id)
    except Contest.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404  # minimum necessary - you can do better
    if datetime.datetime.now() < contest.end_date:  # model field rather than module constants
        return contest(request, contest_id)  # CookieWizardView
    else:
        return contestclosed(request, contest_id)  # TemplateView
```

This is basically your `contest_switcher` with improvements:

- Applies to multiple contests
- Contests know their own end date so you don't clutter your module scope with constants
- Simple `urls.py` and the view does the work of delegating what is shown (you know, the *view*)

(Note that this example implies that you would change your models correspondingly and import all the correct libraries and such.)